# Why tutorials from TensorFlow do not use classes?

Tags: oop, tensorflow

Why don't tutorials from TensorFlow use classes?
I.e. no OOP practices are used in all [tutorials from TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/).

Is it something conceptual? Is it matter of taste? Does something block the models from using OOP? 
I would really appreciate if someone can give me at least basic explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use classes with Tensorflow (as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519890/how-to-use-tensorflow-in-oop-style) shows).

As to why they're not used in the tutorials, I can only guess the choice was made to avoid adding another layer of complexity to understand the basic principles of Tensorflow. Understanding the graph, how TF variables relate to Python variables and TF scoping is hard enough without classes.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevent you from using classes to implement your models. Have a look to [this very nice post](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/) on how you could structure your TensorFlow models in an Object Oriented way in Python.